# Get gradle play plugin to use alternative application.conf

Tags: gradle, configuration, playframework-2.0, configuration-files

I am trying to get my play application to use a different application.conf. I have both application.conf and dev_application.conf in the conf directory. I've tried setting jvmargs off of fork options, but it doesn't seem to work, or even throw an error. My build.gradle can be seen here:

https://pastebin.com/C8FkM4Kb

But the important part is

```
binaries.all {
            tasks.withType(PlayRun) {
               forkOptions.jvmArgs = ["-Dconfig.resource=dev_application.conf"]
            }
        }
```

Then I try to run gradle runPlayBinary, and I always get the regular application.conf instead of the dev_application.conf

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

move tasks.withType(PlayRun) to global scope seems work.